# Combobox disappearing in LibreOffice

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have genrated a (.xlsx) file. Which has combox in column E, F, G for all rows. They are dependent ones.
Till this everything works fine. My problem is: When I make some changes in this file and save it. On whichever row I enter some content, comboxes till that row remains as they are. After that row the combobox disappers. The The named ranges which I have assigned to create dependent comboboxes exists in workbook.

This problem can be observed on Ubuntu LibreOffice only. I test it on Windows, It works perfectly.
Here combobox can be seen on E10 cell.
[image]

Here combobox has disappeared after I save and reopened file.

[image]

Comment: Is this an `apache poi` problem? What happens if you are creating the data validation using Excel and then opening and saving in Ubuntu Libreoffice? The same? If so, then it is not an `apache poi` problem but an issue with Ubuntu Libreoffice.

Comment: Yes, this issue is with Ubuntu LibreOffice. I tried creating one sample file. It behaved the same way.

Comment: So this is neither an `apache poi` problem nor a `Java` problem and so does not suit to this Q/A site. Will better suit to [superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu).